# Design box with position in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, overlapping

I tried to design the attached box, but I failed...

The first time, I used negative margins.

The second time, I used `position: absolute`.

---

**The target:** I'd like to design a box similar at the image below:

[image: Target]

---

**The code:**

```css
.DaD {
    width: 240px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: #2af6ca
}

.Son1DaD {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left:50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2BCE73;
}

.Son1DaD p {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.Son2DaD {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="float1css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="DaD">
            <div class="Son1DaD">
                <p>$29</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Son2DaD">
                <h2>Test For Test</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need negative `margin` because you can use negative `top` due this div has `position:absolute`.
2. To put the `.Son1DaD` in the center you need to set his left to `50%` then push it right exactly to to center - `transform: translateX(-50%);`

```css
body {
  background:#F6F6F6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
}

.DaD {
  width: 240px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:1px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.Son1DaD {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* margin-left: 50px; */
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #5BBDC6;
  top: -45px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color:#fff;
}
.Son1DaD p {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.Son2DaD {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  color:#A7A7A7;
}

.Son2DaD h2 {
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div class="DaD">
      <div class="Son1DaD">
        <p>$29</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Son2DaD">
        <h2>Test For Test</h2>
        <!--<hr>-->
        Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum 
        Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/zixete/edit?html,css,output

Comment: thank you could you redesign this image i uploaded it please

Comment: Although you can't ask for someone who do your job on StackOverflow, I did this for you. Please, do not ask for this. If you have a specific question, ask and we will happy to answer.

Comment: I like your solution, it's fun to play with: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e486c908d5b1c604d6ba2f4dccc2f996

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use Bootstrap Framework

Link : https://jsfiddle.net/kq6xzkag/9 (according to your design)

Font Used Robot! (Google Fonts)

Font Awesome Used for "Star".

Also I Would recommend you to Explore it yourself rather than asking your design work to be done here.

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.white-box {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #DCDCDC;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.star {
  background: #5BBDC6;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: -20px;
  left: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.box-hd {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.box-txt {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="white-box">
        <div class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="box-hd">Exclusive Information</div>
        <div class="box-txt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quam ipsum aliquam facere quasi, nostrum maxime.
        </div>
      </div><!--white-box end-->
    </div><!--col-md-* end-->
  </div><!--row end-->
</div><!--container end-->
```

Comment: Hi @ashwin You don't need to include an entire css framework (bootstrap) to style one div. Also, if you look at his code, he doesn't want to include a "star" he just wants to create a similar layout. So FontAwesome is also not required.

Comment: Yup, thats upto him.. Also he has shown the image,hence i designed accordingly and gave suggestions. Hence As I mentioned it's upto him to explore and fiddle around with the code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add one another div in `.Son1DaD`. Like this:

```html
<div class="DaD">
  <div class="Son1DaD">
    <div><p>$29</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Son2DaD">
    <h2>Test For Test</h2>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.Son1DaD {
  text-align: center;
}
.Son1DaD  div {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2BCE73; 
  display: inline-block; 
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-top: -53px;
}
.Son1DaD p {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

Here is your design code:
I have used Bootstarp and for star icon i have used Font awesome.
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: thank you could you redesign this image i uploaded it please

Answer (score 0):

you can use `top position and left: 50%`

```css
.DaD {
    width: 240px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: #2af6ca
}
.Son1DaD {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -37px;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2BCE73;
}
.Son1DaD p {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.Son2DaD {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="float1css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="DaD">
            <div class="Son1DaD">
                <p>$29</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Son2DaD">
                <h2>Test For Test</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative `margin`.

There is no need to use `position: absolute`, instead use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to keep it centred.

```css
.Son1DaD {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -47.5px auto 0; /* -(75/2) - 10. half the height plus all the margin above it */
  background-color: #2BCE73;
}
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/xVMWXN